# Retrieving Facebook page feed

Tags: facebook

I know this has been (seemingly) asked before, but the Facebook API changes so regularly historic answers are no longer relevant.

I want to show the latest 5 Facebook items from a page's feed on a website. It is actually the website associated with the same organisation as the page, but I'm not an admin on the page.

I've worked out I (probably) need "Page Public Content Access Feature".

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-content-access) for 'allowed usage' say:

> Provide competitive benchmark analysis.

taking this literally, my use case doesn't seem to align with this. Does this mean that my "app" won't get approved?

This must be a common use case: developers are rarely also responsible for social media, so there's no reason for a developer to have admin rights for the Facebook Page. Am I missing a much simpler way to achieve what I want?

Comment: How did you get on with this? In the same situation.